# Zenity entry and sudo -S not working properly without shell

Tags: bash, sudo, zenity

I have problem with `zenity entry` and `sudo -S`.

I am doing something like this:

```
zenity --entry --title 'title' --text 'text' --hide-text | sudo -S pm-suspend
```

If I run this in shell, it's working. But I put it into file and I am launching this script with key shortcut. It's not working!

I've tried to replace `pm-suspend` with my own script, which prints `id -u` to file. But no file was created.

Any ideas, where could be a problem? Thank you

Comment: Does it display the entry box?

Comment: Yes, it displays. The problem was with sudo itself. I've posted the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks terrible but you could use:

```
xterm -e "zenity --entry --title 'title' --text 'text' --hide-text | sudo -S pm-suspend"
```

If anyone knows how to hide xterm, or another solution, please share.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the (1) script and (2) the place where you run it.

For example, it is possible that your environment where you start the script has other `PATH` or other environment variable.

Can you please show the script and how do you start it?

Comment: I've posted the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out, what was problem..

`sudo` is not running without `tty`. So it's necessary to edit `/etc/sudoers` file and delete requiretty line.

Comment: No, `sudo` can run without tty of course! There are many scripts that use `sudo` and they run without any tty!!

Comment: Give me some example of such a script ;) (with requiretty line in /etc/sudoers file)

Answer (score 0):

There has been a kde-sudo package around for ages. Just look in your package manager for sudo. It will let you authenticate through a GUI. Doing it with a prompt-generator is really tacky.

So in you script you will do:

```
kdesudo
privilegedcommand
```

There is a similar thread on Superuser about this, perhaps someone has said something about gnome:

https://superuser.com/questions/135311/sudo-access-for-desktop-actions-in-gnome-kde